# Free remote screen sharing from Android to Windows over WLAN

Tags: windows, gratis, android, screen-sharing

I am looking for a free Android app that (at a minimum) shares the screen of my Android device. I have looked online but they all do not meet at least one of the requirements below

My question is: What app can share my Android's screen to a Windows machine?

Requirements:

- Must work on Windows (No admin privileges)
- No rooting of Android device
- Does not require sharing over Internet
- Actually shares the screen to a Windows machine (minimum 1 frame per 3 seconds)
- Must be free
- Must be "live" (at most 60 seconds delay from "live" screen)

Notes:

- Audio is not required, only the screen (at least 360 x 480)
- ads are fine, as long as they are not too invasive
- Custom solutions are ok (ie. self-build from source code)
- the computer is running Windows 7 and the mobile is running Android 4.x 
  (I'm not sure of x right now)

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running marshmellow (and nougat works for me) - the miracast based "cast screen" feature in android and "project to this display" in windows 10 anniversery edition or better work together.

Completely native on both platforms, connects over wifi direct with very very little lag and costs nothing.

Supposedly works better on newer hardware but I have had no trouble doing this on a modern marshmellow and nougat phone (an OP3) and most windows 10 boxen.

Howogeek [has a great article](http://www.howtogeek.com/200897/how-to-use-miracast-screen-mirroring-from-windows-or-android/) on the details, but its pretty intuitive.